# gcov instrumented shared object referencing __gcov_init hidden symbol

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gcov

I have a  main linux executable and that executable is using some functions from a dynamic shared object. When I instrument the shared object and try also to instrument and compile the main executable it gives me a error like in bellow.

hidden symbol: `__gcov_init` in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcov/libgcov.a(_gcov.o) is referenced by DSO.

My question is,

[1] Is this happen exactly due to the shared library is referencing back to main  executable ? or static object libgcov.a ?

[2] How can I overcome this issue ? In windows there is no way that shared object reference back to main executable, but in linux this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared libraries that I've talked about does not instrumented and linked with 'lgcov'. We need all those libraries linked with that [ if there exists a single object file which compiled for instrumented built ] and instrumented.

That solved my issue and I've able to instrument my codebase.